# Problem typing Subscript for a set of vectors

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I want to type `k$\in$I` as a subscript of `\{$f_k$\}` but am having trouble with

```
$\{$$f_k$$\}_{k$$\in$$ I}$
```

How should this be done?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your main error is to enter and exit from math mode: `$k\in I$` is the correct input; for the subscript, `$\{f_k\}_{k\in I}$`

Answer (score 2):

Your error is going in and out of math mode: formulas should be typed as a single entity.

```
$\{f_k\}_{k\in I}$
```